# Basic FunctionN cov/contravariance

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I have pretty much a code organized like this:

```
class Person(name: String, val addr: Int) {
  def distance(that: Person) = this.addr - that.addr
}

class Employee(_name: String, role: String, _addr: Int) extends Person(_name, _addr) {
  def smgth = 1
}


val anna = new Employee("Anna", "Secretary", 1)
val boss = new Employee("Boss", "Boss", 2)


def filterP(l: List[Person]) = l filter { (x) => x.addr > 1 }
def fltrdEmployees(l: List[Employee]): List[Employee] = filterP(l)
```

which gives:

```
Error:(19, 65) type mismatch;
 found   : List[A$A126.this.Person]
 required: List[A$A126.this.Employee]
def fltrdEmployees(l: List[Employee]): List[Employee] = filterP(l);}
                                                           ^
```

I understand it is a [probl with cov](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2013/02/21/be-friend-with-covariance-and-contravariance/). I have seen cov-contra-variance [being applied to classes](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html) in the classic `Box[T]` example.

I am also somehow aware of the [FunctionN object](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/functional-scala-functions-as-objects-as-functions/)

How to fix this? Do I need to wrap the stuff in an adhoc object that exposes my desired method? Is there something cleaner (and possibly) shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by making `filterP` generic:

```
def filterP[T <: Person](l: List[T]) = l filter { (x) => x.addr > 1 }
```

The covariance of `List` is what allows you to supply a `List[Employee]` where a `List[Person]` is required, however the problem is that a `List[Person]` is being returned which is not compatible with `List[Employee]`. Making it generic allows the element type of the input list to be maintained.